# Disable pn53x_check_communication: Input / Output Error message

Tags: c, lib-nfc

I'm using libnfc 1.7.1 compiled with c to read from a PN532 reader on a Raspberry Pi.  The goal is to make a node for Node-RED that injects the UID of the scanned card or pass errors along about library or reader.  I modified the example to give me the UID of a card as the only normal output.  I can't have anything printed other than an error when the library can't be loaded, an error when the reader can't be connected, or the UID of the card.  I changed the log level to 0 in /etc/nfc/libnfc.conf but my program is still printing "pn53x_check_communication: Input / Output Error" (unwanted) as well as "ERROR: Unable to open NFC device." (wanted)  I can't find any way to disable the I/O error message.  I looked in the library and found [this](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/14f48d012281f495904566ffd93305623017cbfa/libnfc/chips/pn53x.c#L1015) that returns NFC_EIO which is the I/O error I'm getting, but can't find anywhere that it actually prints that. Short of modifying the library I can't find any way to disable this print.  If there is nothing that can be done I can program my node to ignore this output but I would rather eliminate it.  My code is below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <nfc/nfc.h>

static void
print_long(const uint8_t *pbtData, const size_t szBytes)
{
  size_t  szPos;

  for (szPos = 0; szPos < szBytes; szPos++) {
    printf("%03lu", pbtData[szPos]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  nfc_device *pnd;
  nfc_target nt;

  // Allocate only a pointer to nfc_context
  nfc_context *context;

  // Initialize libnfc and set the nfc_context
  nfc_init(&context);
  if (context == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to init libnfc (malloc)\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Open, using the first available NFC device which can be in order of selection:
  //   - default device specified using environment variable or
  //   - first specified device in libnfc.conf (/etc/nfc) or
  //   - first specified device in device-configuration directory (/etc/nfc/devices.d) or
  //   - first auto-detected (if feature is not disabled in libnfc.conf) device
  pnd = nfc_open(context, NULL);

  //Send error
  if (pnd == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", "Unable to open NFC device.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Set opened NFC device to initiator mode
  if (nfc_initiator_init(pnd) < 0) {
    nfc_perror(pnd, "nfc_initiator_init");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while(true){
    // Poll for a ISO14443A (MIFARE) tag
    const nfc_modulation nmMifare = {
      .nmt = NMT_ISO14443A,
      .nbr = NBR_106,
    };

    //Print decimal version of UID and wait until it's removed to scan again
    if (nfc_initiator_select_passive_target(pnd, nmMifare, NULL, 0, &nt) > 0) {
      print_long(nt.nti.nai.abtUid, nt.nti.nai.szUidLen);
      while (0 == nfc_initiator_target_is_present(pnd, NULL)) {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you try `yourprogram 2> /dev/null` ? libnfc seems to properly print its errors on stderr.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I'm not familiar with C so didn't even think about stderr.